# LDAP on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ldap

I am planning to install a LDAP server on an EC2 instance. The requirement is to have the admin console to be accessible for users in our intranet. Please suggest the best open source product.

Thanks in advance,
Kotesh

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [ApacheDS](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/) on EC2. It has [ApacheDS Studio](https://directory.apache.org/studio/) which is eclipse like application which has extensive features and tools to manage the LDAP. I have ApacheDS running on EC2 while the studio is installed on my local machine and it works great.

BTW, ApacheDs is Java based LDAP.

Comment: Thanks "slayedbylucifer". I am actually leaning towards 389ds.

Comment: how can I install apacheds on ec2?